# ActionScript 3 - target not recognizing where it is dropped

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, drag-and-drop

I have two MovieClips (dragable, and targetm). I want my ActionScript so that I can drag targetm and if I place targetm in dragable, then it remains in dragable, otherwise it resets to its original location. This is my ActionScript:

```
dragable.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, pickup);
dragable.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, place);

var startingLocation = new Point();

function pickup(evt:MouseEvent) {

    startingLocation.x = evt.target.x;
    startingLocation.y = evt.target.y;

    evt.target.startDrag();
}

function place(evt:MouseEvent) {
    if (evt.target.dropTarget == targetm) {

        trace('here');
        evt.target.stopDrag();

    } else {

        evt.target.stopDrag();
        evt.target.x = startingLocation.x;
        evt.target.y = startingLocation.y;
    }
}
```

but even if I drag and drop dragable on top of targetm, it does not trace anything. It goes to the else statement and resets the location of dragable. How come it does not trace anything even when I place dragabale on top of targetm?

note: If I do

```
trace(evt.target.dropTarget);
```

it traces

```
[object Shape]
```

if I drop dragable on targetm.

Answer (score 1):

When you drop is the entire dragable within the targetm? If not, then your **mouse cursor** will have to be over targetm to get a trace.

Answer (score 0):

Something else may be on the display list that is being returned for `evt.target.dropTarget;` **@Craig** is also correct that the mouse cursor does have to reside over the display object. Since that may or may not be the case, and in the future you may or may not have something there anyway, I would suggest doing this based on position instead. For this, I'm going to suggest using getBounds, so both coordinate systems of your `dropTarget` and `targetm`, reside in the same coordinate space:

```
function place(evt:MouseEvent):void {
    var targetBounds:Rectangle = evt.target.getBounds( stage );
    var targetmBounds:Rectangle = targetm.getBounds( stage );

    if (targetBounds.intersects(targetmBounds)) {
        trace('here');
        evt.target.stopDrag();  
    } else {
        evt.target.stopDrag();
        evt.target.x = startingLocation.x;
        evt.target.y = startingLocation.y;
    }
}
```